# Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hi I am trying to hide a div when the page loads and display/hide it when a checkbox is checked/unchecked. This is my code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" runat="server" Text="CB" />

<div runat="server" id="div1" style="display:none">
</div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
    $('#cb1').change(function () {
        display('div1');
    })
}

function display(id) {
    var traget = document.getElementById(id);
    if (traget.style.display == "none") {
        traget.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        traget.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

The error i get is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

This is the last version of my code. I have already tryed stuff like:

```
document.getElementById('div1').style.display="block";
$('#div1').hide();
```

... and many other options.

The result is the same. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `runat="server"` so try this

```
<%= div1.ClientID %>
```

to get the Id of the div and then you can call you function like this

```
display('<%= div1.ClientID %>');
```

or use `clientidmode="static"` in the markup

```
<div runat="server" id="div1" style="display:none" clientidmode="static">
</div>
```

Comment: actually here must be place it: `display('<%= div1.ClientID %>');` base on the user code and function

Comment: thanks @Aristos I missed that function call. Modified the post :)

Comment: ok i did this and the error is gone but now the code does nothing. It does not show/hide the div. There are no other errors on the page

Comment: @Gesh its working as expected make sure your function is calling. as you are also using runat="server" for your checkbox http://jsfiddle.net/7bcxy/

Comment: Check your developer tools, if you're using chrome then you can do Ctrl+Shift+I > Source and check for errors in the file. If you're using IE then you can press F12 and check the source. If you're using some other browsers then you can try firebug.

Comment: Weird! I checked and the page loads but the row $('#cb1').change(function () { does not execute. I made chrome pause on all errors and exceptions and there are none

Comment: @Gesh try this `$('#'+'<%= div1.ClientID %>').change(function ()`

Answer (score 1):

```
function display(id) {
    if ($('#'+id).css('display') === 'none') {
        $('#'+id).show();
    } else {
        $('#'+id).hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this and there is no error but now the code does nothing. It does not show/hide the div and there are no other errors on the page

Comment: then are sure about your "id" ?

Comment: waht is the jquery version that you are using ? did you try this ?

$('#cb1').on('change',function () {
        display('div1');
})

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
window.onload = function () {
    $('#<%= cb1.ClientID %>').change(function () {
        display('<%= div1.ClientID %>');
    })
}

function display(id) {
   $('#'+id).toggle();
}
```